# Loop that asks for userinput for an arraylist that consists of ints.Loop exits when string is entered

Tags: java, arraylist

This program should use only arraylists.A loop should be used that continues to ask for the userinput consisting of whole numbers.Every userinput should be added to the arraylist.The loop should execute 10 times but if the user wants to exit early, the letter x is entered.

Initially, I confused as to how two different variable types can be used within the same array.However,as **arraylists** are being used,this is possible.The below pasted code is what came up with.I thought I could use a boolean to check the arraylist for the letter x. However,it shows an exception if x is entered.Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayList {
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter=0;
        ArrayList myList=new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {

        System.out.print("Enter whole number.Enter x to quit: ");
         int userinput=a.nextInt();
        myList.add(userinput);

        boolean element=myList.contains("q");
        if(element=true)
        {
            System.out.println("Doesn't contain q.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Contains q.");
        }
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: There should be two equal signs in your if statement that checks if element is true. Why are you checking if the list contains "q"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a.nextInt** will throw Exception if user enters a non integer value.
So you need to check type of the input with **hasNextInt()** before processing.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList myList=new ArrayList();
        for(int i= 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter whole number.Enter x to quit: ");
            if (a.hasNextInt()) {
                int userinput=a.nextInt();
                myList.add(userinput);
            }
            else if (a.next().equals("x")) {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(myList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Name of the class should not be same as the other class. Though the actual `ArrayList` class in `util.*` is templated but then too, this should be avoided.

Secondly, 
The input that you are taking from the user, you are directly converting it to `int` by calling `.nextInt()`. This gives exception when `'x'`  is entered.

Instead of that try using this utility from `StringUtils.`

```
if(StringUtils.isNumeric(a.toString()))
{
 int userinput=a.nextInt();
}
else
{
 //check if input is 'x'
 //else
 //call 'continue;'
}
```

Hope this helps.